# How to disable auto restoring of non-removable applications in Android 10?

Tags: android-10

I have Android 10 in my Samsung A12. There were about 10 applications that had to be installed by phone producer in the country I bought that phone. Using ADB and command `pm uninstall --user 0 ...` I removed all this garbage and was very glad. However, when I connected internet Android showed me message, something like "restoring preinstalled applications" and restored all applications I removed.

How to disable this auto restoring?

Comment: Please update question if rooting is option for you (lose warranty, knox, banking, etc)

Comment: @alecxs The phone is new (less one month) and I wouldn't like to loose warranty, knox etc. But if there is no other way, then I will consider all advantages and disadvantages of the solution.

Comment: already tried basic things like disable auto-update of system apps in settings or developer options?

Comment: @alecxs No, because I think there are only global settings, but the question is about these non-removable apps. At the same time I can be wrong here.

Comment: @alecxs As I understand, you don't recommend rooting for this command `pm uninstall --user 0 ...`. If I am right, then what should I use?